# PHP Grid only show Edit/Delete link only on first row

Tags: jqgrid, phpgrid

I am using [phpgrid.org](http://www.phpgrid.org). It only show Edit/Delete link only on first row. Some times it show randomly. How to fix it?

Comment: Your question should include the *exact* code you are running, and the *exact* error message or malfunction you are seeing. See also how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first column of grid must have unique alphanumeric data (usually a PK). This is required to uniquely identify particular row for update & delete operations.

Refer their faqs as well: http://phpgrid.org/faqs